# How to embed errata in math?

Tags: math-mode

How to add an errata (from errata package) in equation but Latex complains:

```
! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\usepackage{errata}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
     \erratumReplace{typo}{$a_{10}$}{$a_{00}$} &=  2 \cdot 6 + (-1)\cdot 4\cdot 1 = 8\\
         a_{10} &=  -(18 - 4) = -14\\
         a_{20} &=  (3 -2) = 1\\
         ||A||&= 1\cdot 8 + 0\cdot (-14)+ 5\cdot 1 =13\;.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That function uses `\marginpar` internally, which can only be used in limited places (due to `\marginpar` creating` a float). It might be possible to patch the command to use `\marginnote` from the `marginnote` package, which just writes to the margin, but never checks if there is enough space in the margin.

Comment: BTW: `||A||` is very wrong, is that a determinant? That is often written `|A|`, if `||` is needed, probably better to use `\lVert A\rVert` for proper spacing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a new command `\erratumMathReplace` that will (should, at least) work in math mode. But as the errata are added in footnotes and these don't work in the `align` environment (thanks @daleif for pointing that out), I created an additional command, `\erratumMathPrint`, that will print the footnote.

The `\erratumMathReplace` works the same way as the original `\erratumReplace`, and the `\erratumMathPrint` has to be issued after the math environment ends.

The code:

```
\usepackage{marginnote}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\erratumMathReplace}[4][]{% keyvals, explanation, old, new
\setkeys{erratum}{#1}\stepcounter{erratum}\record@erratum{#2}%
\marginnote{Err(\arabic{erratum})}\immediate\typeout{Erratum!}%
[#4]_r^{\arabic{erratum}}%
\gdef\erratumMath@new{#2}%
\gdef\erratumMath@old{#3}}
\newcommand{\erratumMathPrint}{%
\footnotetext[\value{erratum}]{\text{{\scshape{Erratum!}}%
\@ifundefined{erratum@type}{}{(\erratum@type)} \(\erratumMath@new\) (original text was: ``\(\erratumMath@old\)'')}}}
\makeatother
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\usepackage{errata}

\usepackage{marginnote}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\erratumMathReplace}[4][]{% keyvals, explanation, old, new
\setkeys{erratum}{#1}\stepcounter{erratum}\record@erratum{#2}%
\marginnote{Err(\arabic{erratum})}\immediate\typeout{Erratum!}%
[#4]_r^{\arabic{erratum}}%
\gdef\erratumMath@new{#2}%
\gdef\erratumMath@old{#3}}
\newcommand{\erratumMathPrint}{%
\footnotetext[\value{erratum}]{\text{{\scshape{Erratum!}}%
\@ifundefined{erratum@type}{}{(\erratum@type)} \(\erratumMath@new\) (original text was: ``\(\erratumMath@old\)'')}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}% Note that the arguments to \erratumMathReplace don't go inside $$
     \erratumMathReplace{typo}{a_{10}}{a_{00}} &=  2 \cdot 6 + (-1)\cdot 4\cdot 1 = 8\\
         a_{10} &=  -(18 - 4) = -14\\
         a_{20} &=  (3 -2) = 1\\
         ||A||&= 1\cdot 8 + 0\cdot (-14)+ 5\cdot 1 =13\;.
\end{align*}
\erratumMathPrint% Printing the footnote
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note the footnote stuff, that probably does not work in math mode either. I'd remove the footnote stuff and move that text into the `\marginnote`, that might work ok.

Comment: Did you test your code, I cannot make it compile without errors

Comment: @daleif Thanks for pointing that out. I preferred to keep the format of the `errata` package and print the errata in footnotes, so I created an additional command to do that. Also posted an example that compiles without errors.

Comment: It just makes the code a lot messier (IMO)

Answer (score 3):

You can coerce `errata` to use `\marginnote` instead of `\marginpar`, which is the main source of the issue.

Also you need `\mbox` around the `errata` commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\usepackage[show]{errata}
\usepackage{marginnote,xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\erratumAdd}{\marginpar}{\marginnote}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\erratumDelete}{\marginpar}{\marginnote}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\erratumReplace}{\marginpar}{\marginnote}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\erratum}{\marginpar}{\marginnote}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\enderratum}{\marginpar}{\marginnote}{}{}

\newcommand{\matherratumAdd}[3][]{%
  \mbox{\erratumAdd[#1]{#2}{\ensuremath{#3}}}%
}
\newcommand{\matherratumDelete}[3][]{%
  \mbox{\erratumDelete[#1]{#2}{\ensuremath{#3}}}%
}
\newcommand{\matherratumReplace}[4][]{%
  \mbox{\erratumReplace[#1]{#2}{\ensuremath{#3}}{\ensuremath{#4}}}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\matherratumReplace{typo}{a_{10}}{a_{00}} &=  2 \cdot 6 + (-1)\cdot 4\cdot 1 = 8\\
         a_{10} &=  -(18 - 4) = -14\\
         a_{20} &=  (3 -2) = 1\\
         ||A||&= 1\cdot 8 + 0\cdot (-14)+ 5\cdot 1 =13\;.
\end{align*}

$\matherratumReplace{typo}{x}{y}$

$\matherratumAdd{typo}{a}$

\erratumAdd{x}{y}

\clearpage

\PrintErrata

\end{document}
```

However, you won't get footnotes. That would be too complex, I'm afraid.

[image]